# Updating an existing object Array in ES6 javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I am a novice of ES6 JavaScript. I am looking for a scenario where i can update an object array that is coming from a web service and pass the data format to a table.

I am using ReactJS 'rc-table'.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-table
```

To display our data in the rc-table format , We need to have an attribute key:"somevalue" in our data that is coming from the backend.

My data is in the following format:

```
{
 {
   Name:'Robert',
   City: 'Barcelona'
 },
 {
   Name: 'Marguaritte',
  City: 'Baltimore'

 }
}
```

Now it will display in rc-table format , only if the object has a unique key attribute.

For Example:

```
 {
 {
  Name:'Robert',
  City: 'Barcelona',
   Key:1
 },
 {
  Name: 'Marguaritte',
  City: 'Baltimore',
  Key:2

  }
 }
```

I am looking for updating my object with 'key:1' and 'key:2'
Attached is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its a bit confusing. Can you please show us the expected output that you need?

Comment: There is nothing in ES6 that would make this easier. You can use any solution you used before in ES5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well your actual array format is incorrect, you should replace wrapping `{}` with `[]` so it's a valid array.

Anyway you should use [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example), it will return a customised array using a callback function that will add the `key` property to each iterated item.

This is how you should write your code:

```
var data = arr.map(function(item, index) {
  item.key = index + 1;
  return item;
});
```

**ES6 Solution:**

Using **[ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** as suggested by [Chester Millisock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4570355/chester-millisock) in comments:

```
var data = arr.map((item, index) => {
   item.key = index + 1;
   return item;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{
    Name: 'Robert',
    City: 'Barcelona'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Marguaritte',
    City: 'Baltimore'

  }
];

var data = arr.map((item, index) => {
   item.key = index + 1;
   return item;
}); 

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Since OP says he/she is a novice to ES6, I'd recommend that OP learn to use arrow functions for this (see below).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do something like this.  I'm assuming your data is an array of objects and not an object without keys, as you suggested.

```
const data = data.map((el, index) => {
    el.Key = index;
    return el;
});
```

Comment: You still need to return `el`, otherwise it's an array of `undefined`, no?

Comment: Actually `index` starts from `0` so we need to use `ìndex+1` and this will always push `indefined` in the result array.

Comment: Yes, you need to return el.  Edited.

Index does start at 0.  I'm assuming 0 is a valid Key for rc-table.